# Autoselect the cheapest UPS shipping rate on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping, ups

I need to auto select the cheapest UPS shipping rate on checkout page.

[image]

in the picture above I need Ground to be selected by default.

we are trying to make our checkout easier for customers and pre-selecting shipping rate is the first step.

**PS**: I tried modifying

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

and had `checked="checked"` placed for the first item and it worked. But grandtotal didn't include shipping cost in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by these code edits:

1. copy `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php`
2. edit `app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php` and make `collectRates` look like this:

   ```
   public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
   {    
   if (!$this->getConfigFlag($this->_activeFlag)) {
       return false;
   }    

   $this->setRequest($request);

   $this->_result = $this->_getQuotes();
   $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);

   #THIS IS MY CUSTOM CODE: START

   try{ 
   $q = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
   if(!$q->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod()){
    if (is_object($this->_result)) {
       foreach($this->_result->getAllRates() as $i=>$item){
           if ($item->getMethod() && $item->getCarrier()){
               $q->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($item->getCarrier().'_'.$item->getMethod());
               break;
           }    
       }    
    }    
   }    
   }catch(Exception $e){}

    #THIS IS MY CUSTOM CODE: FINISH

   return $this->getResult();
   }
   ```

now the cheapest option is preselected on checkout and on cart shipping estimator.

thanks all.

Comment: This ignores any promotional rule applied on shipping  rate

Comment: could be but we don't use promotional rules in our case

Comment: @KonstantinGerasimov  In my cart page ESTIMATE SHIPPING AND TAX, UPS display shipping price, but checkout page UPS not showing. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can fire a JS click  method after page load like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(function($) {
    $('input[name="shipping_method"]').get(0).click;
});
//]]>
```

You can use the same thing on specific element id of `Ground`

Comment: your answer won't work on cart page in shipping calculator. I want magento to preselect the cheapest option there too.